# Tenenbaum and Pollard ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Exercise 10, question 14. I cannot work this out after hours of trying. The suggested integrating factor does not seem to make the equation exact. 
Any help most appreciated.

Comment: Not everybody has access to the book. You should type out the question, your concerns, and what you have tried.

Comment: What is the question?